# Update AD Group based on CSV File

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have an AD Group I keep up-to-date based on a CSV file. Users not present in the file should be removed from the AD Group.

```
#Import New List
$NewList= (Import-Csv E:\Group_Update\newlist.csv).SamAccountName

#backup old members
Get-ADGroupMember LAB_HR | select SamAccountName | Export-Csv E:\Group_Update\Group_B4_update.csv -NoTypeInformation

# Get old members 
$oldusers= (Get-ADGroupMember LAB_HR | select SamAccountName).SamAccountName

# List group members not listed in the new list -- To be Deleted 
$RemoveMembers= $oldusers | where {$NewList -notcontains $_}


# add new members
foreach ($user in $NewList) {

Add-ADGroupMember lAB_HR $user 
Write-Host $user "has been added to Group"

}

# delete members not in the new list
foreach ($remove in $RemoveMembers){

Remove-ADGroupMember LAB_HR $remove -Confirm:$false

Write-Host $remove "has been removed from group "
}
```

Comment: so ... what is your Question? [*grin*]

Comment: I'm just sharing what I got here, and very welcome if anyone suggest a better way for do the same function. thanks :)

Comment: ah! ok, here are a few comments [*grin*] ... [1] you are making two calls to grab the OldMembers of that group. i would make that call only _one time_. [2] you are adding the New members and then removing the Old ones that are not in the new list. have you thot about just removing ALL the group members and then adding the new ones?